# Append data instead of replace with UpdateView Django

Tags: django, django-generic-views

Simple question, whenever I try to update my view, in this case by adding more users `UpdateView` replaces previous records and add selected one. To avoid that, I need to select those which are already in db and a new one. How to avoid replacing, and append data to db?

views.py

```
class AddPersonView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    model = Trip
    template_name = 'tripplanner/add_new_member.html'
    fields = ["profile"]
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
   path('trip/<int:pk>/add_person/', AddPersonView.as_view(), name='new-trip-member'),
```

Comment: I have to use UpdateView, because that's an operation on already existing records and I want to give a user possibility to append new users.

Comment: can you add the `url route` file because i want to know how you are calling the `AddPersonView`

Comment: @SureshKumar Done

Comment: while calling the `AddPersonView` you need to pass the `pk` of the records in `Trip` model to the url to update the record. I think you are calling with the user records `pk`

Comment: @SureshKumar I'm sorry, but you didn't understand the problem. Everything is working here. The problem is, that when I update record I want to append data to existing record. In default `UpdateView` replaces this record.

Comment: `UpdateView` donot `replace` the existing record it just `edits` or `changes` the existing record.[Refer this to know about update view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView)

Comment: @Hiddenguy can I see your Trip model?

Comment: I think you are using the author as a foreign key to Trip model and I think you are trying to update the author/User fields instead of Trip fields and I think update view can't directly edit the foreign key.

Comment: If it's a FK relationship use a modelformsetfactory (probably an inline one), but my susppicion is you have an M2M relationship. Can you show your models please.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement before, but i was using DRF and was able to make it work. In django you can try the below code.

Since you have mentioned you need to add multiple users, either you have to set that field as many-many or one-many (foreign key).

Below example might help you, it is not tested, modify as per your need

**models.py**

```
class Trip(models.Models):
    authors= models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='authors') # list of users will be appended to this field
```

**views.py**

```
class AddPersonView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    model = Trip
    template_name = 'tripplanner/add_new_member.html'
    fields = ["profile"]
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.authors.add(self.request.user)
        return super(AddPersonView,self).form_valid(form)
```